# Numerical optimization in function space

Tags: calculus-of-variations, numerical-optimization

I'm new to calculus of variations. I'm curious about how to apply simple numerical optimization techniques in function space.

Consider the classical problem: finding the shortest path between two points on a plane. Let these points be $A=(x_1,y_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2)$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$. The path is parameterized by $(x,f(x))$ for $x \in [x_1,x_2]$, where $f(x_1) = y_1$ and $f(x_2) = y_2$.

It is easy to show that the path can be formalized as:

$I( f )=\underset{{{x}_{1}}}{\overset{{{x}_{2}}}{\mathop \int }}\,{{( 1+{{( {{f}^{'}} )}^{2}} )}^{\frac{1}{2}}}dx$.

I want to find $f$ such that the shortest path between $A$ and $B$ is minimized. I'd like to start with an initial $f_0$ and update it via a gradient descent procedure.

for $t:1 \to T$

$f_t \leftarrow f_{t-1} - \eta \nabla_f I$

end

where $\eta$ is suitably selected real number. Perhaps the loop can contain an if statement to check whether $f_t$ satisfies the Euler–Lagrange Equation and if so halts.

My questions are:

1) Is $\nabla_f I$ calculated similar to ordinary differentiation, i.e. treating function $f$ as a variable?

2) Is the above update step reasonable, if so how to subtract (or add) two functions?